# Custom CallAdapter for Retrofit 2 and threading issue on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, retrofit2

In Retrofit2, when I use a custom CallAdapter for error handling that Retrofit provides on [samples/ErrorHandlingAdapter.java](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/ErrorHandlingAdapter.java), the callback methods executed on a background thread instead of the main thread, unlike the default CallAdapter (Call), which is executed on the main thread. I made sure of that by running Thread.currentThread().getName() on both

This is a big problem for me. I don't want to use the runOnUiThread method every time I want to do something in ui-thread.

The source code of ErrorHandlingAdapter mentioned above:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2015 Square, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.example.retrofit;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.CallAdapter;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

/**
 * A sample showing a custom {@link CallAdapter} which adapts the built-in {@link Call} to a custom
 * version whose callback has more granular methods.
 */
public final class ErrorHandlingAdapter {
  /** A callback which offers granular callbacks for various conditions. */
  interface MyCallback<T> {
    /** Called for [200, 300) responses. */
    void success(Response<T> response);
    /** Called for 401 responses. */
    void unauthenticated(Response<?> response);
    /** Called for [400, 500) responses, except 401. */
    void clientError(Response<?> response);
    /** Called for [500, 600) response. */
    void serverError(Response<?> response);
    /** Called for network errors while making the call. */
    void networkError(IOException e);
    /** Called for unexpected errors while making the call. */
    void unexpectedError(Throwable t);
  }

  interface MyCall<T> {
    void cancel();
    void enqueue(MyCallback<T> callback);
    MyCall<T> clone();

    // Left as an exercise for the reader...
    // TODO MyResponse<T> execute() throws MyHttpException;
  }

  public static class ErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory extends CallAdapter.Factory {
    @Override public CallAdapter<?, ?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations,
        Retrofit retrofit) {
      if (getRawType(returnType) != MyCall.class) {
        return null;
      }
      if (!(returnType instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
            "MyCall must have generic type (e.g., MyCall<ResponseBody>)");
      }
      Type responseType = getParameterUpperBound(0, (ParameterizedType) returnType);
      Executor callbackExecutor = retrofit.callbackExecutor();
      return new ErrorHandlingCallAdapter<>(responseType, callbackExecutor);
    }

    private static final class ErrorHandlingCallAdapter<R> implements CallAdapter<R, MyCall<R>> {
      private final Type responseType;
      private final Executor callbackExecutor;

      ErrorHandlingCallAdapter(Type responseType, Executor callbackExecutor) {
        this.responseType = responseType;
        this.callbackExecutor = callbackExecutor;
      }

      @Override public Type responseType() {
        return responseType;
      }

      @Override public MyCall<R> adapt(Call<R> call) {
        return new MyCallAdapter<>(call, callbackExecutor);
      }
    }
  }

  /** Adapts a {@link Call} to {@link MyCall}. */
  static class MyCallAdapter<T> implements MyCall<T> {
    private final Call<T> call;
    private final Executor callbackExecutor;

    MyCallAdapter(Call<T> call, Executor callbackExecutor) {
      this.call = call;
      this.callbackExecutor = callbackExecutor;
    }

    @Override public void cancel() {
      call.cancel();
    }

    @Override public void enqueue(final MyCallback<T> callback) {
      call.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
        @Override public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
          // TODO if 'callbackExecutor' is not null, the 'callback' methods should be executed
          // on that executor by submitting a Runnable. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

          int code = response.code();
          if (code >= 200 && code < 300) {
            callback.success(response);
          } else if (code == 401) {
            callback.unauthenticated(response);
          } else if (code >= 400 && code < 500) {
            callback.clientError(response);
          } else if (code >= 500 && code < 600) {
            callback.serverError(response);
          } else {
            callback.unexpectedError(new RuntimeException("Unexpected response " + response));
          }
        }

        @Override public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
          // TODO if 'callbackExecutor' is not null, the 'callback' methods should be executed
          // on that executor by submitting a Runnable. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

          if (t instanceof IOException) {
            callback.networkError((IOException) t);
          } else {
            callback.unexpectedError(t);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    @Override public MyCall<T> clone() {
      return new MyCallAdapter<>(call.clone(), callbackExecutor);
    }
  }
}
```

In Android, I added the ErrorHandlingAdapter to Retrofit before doing any calls:

```
// Initializing retrofit
BooleanTypeAdapter typeAdapter = new BooleanTypeAdapter();
    gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().registerTypeAdapter(boolean.class, typeAdapter).create();
    apiService = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_API_URL)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(new ErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
        .create(ApiService.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get callback on main thread you should use the `callbackExecutor` provided in MyCallAdapter.

```
callbackExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        int code = response.code();
                        if (code >= 200 && code < 300) {
                            callback.success(response);
                        } else if (code == 401) {
                            callback.unauthenticated(response);
                        } else if (code >= 400 && code < 500) {
                            callback.clientError(response);
                        } else if (code >= 500 && code < 600) {
                            callback.serverError(response);
                        } else {
                            callback.unexpectedError(new RuntimeException("Unexpected response " + response));
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Sample has a TODO written:

> // TODO if 'callbackExecutor' is not null, the 'callback' methods should be executed
>                       // on that executor by submitting a Runnable. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

It is an Retrofit callback executor which runs on UI thread in android.

[See here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/962) & [here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/Callback.html)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to deal with it being on the other thread, that's just the nature of asynchronous libraries.  If you only have the one error handler, then it's not too big a burden to make the needed threading calls.  If you have multiple, then you could make a lightweight delegating implementation and reuse.

Your other alternative is to dive into using an rxjava implementation which gives precise threading control.